# Uncaught TypeError: autocomplete is not a function

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

While running the project it is showing "autocomplete" is not a function. I tried using different library link but no luck. Here "GetStudents" is JSON Result method which return JSON.

**Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
    at HTMLDocument. (Index:54)
    at fire (jquery-1.10.2.js:3048)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.10.2.js:3160)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.10.2.js:433)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.10.2.js:104)**

```
@model IEnumerable<TestAuto.Models.Student>

    <link href="~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
                source: '@Url.Action("GetStudents")'
            });
        });

    </script>


    <div style="font-family:Arial">
        @using (@Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <b>Name:</b>
            @Html.TextBox("SearchTerm", null, new { id="txtSearch"})
            <input type="button" value="Search" />
        }
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TotalMarks)
                </th>

            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalMarks)
                    </td>

                </tr>
            }

        </table>
    </div>

public JsonResult GetStudents(string term)
        {
            List<string> Students;

                Students = db.Students.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(term))
                .Select(y=>y.Name).ToList();

            return Json(Students,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Comment: The error would suggest that you are not loading the jQuery autocomplete library - how are you referencing it in your page?

Comment: @DigiFriend, i have loaded this 3 libraries which works for lower version MVC3 but not in higher version like MVC5.Please suggest me what to do. Any suggestion and help is highly appreciated.

Comment: check in console if the jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js was loaded successfully , if so put the jqu and jqui script at the bottom of the page

Comment: @bRIMOs, i tried putting those reference library at the bottom of the page but still the error is coming "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Index:41". Please guide me. Thanks

Comment: please put your script also after those script tag